# Do an animation in 1 command in gnuplot

Tags: animation, gnuplot

I'm trying to show an animation using gnuplot
I got the following script:

```
plot   ”heat1d.txt ”  using   1:2   every   :::a::a 
pause   0.01
a=a+1
if ( a<b )   reread
```

that I execute using

```
a = 0
b = 100
load "a.plot"
```

it works, but is there a way to execute all of this using only 1 command from a shell?
Alternatively is there a way to integrate the variable definitions into the .plot file so that I can simply execute it? I tried different things like `echo 'a=0'|gnuplot` etc but it doesn't seem to actually define the variable correctly

thanks

Comment: This question might be better suited for superuser.

Comment: @frb : alright, is there anyway I can manually move the question?

Comment: @frb -- I don't see any problem with this on stackoverflow ... Why do you think it would be better suited for SuperUser?

Answer (score 3):

You can use a do for loop.

```
do for [a = 0:100] {
  plot   ”heat1d.txt ”  using   1:2   every   :::a::a 
  pause   0.01
}
```

The default terminal on linux is usually `wxt`, and it has the `raise` option, which will change the focus to the plot window at every iteration. This will make it difficult if not impossible to stop the animation.

I suggest to put `noraise` as the terminal option. For example, you can put the following line at the beginning of the script:

```
set term wxt noraise
```

Now, if you want to stop the animation halfway, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> on the gnuplot terminal.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass `-e` as a commandline argument.  For example, if you have the script:

```
#script test.gp
print foo,bar
```

Then you could run it with gnuplot using:

```
gnuplot -e "foo=1;bar=2" test.gp
```

In your case, it looks like you could accomplish nearly what you want by invoking your script as:

```
gnuplot -e "a=0;b=100" a.plot
```